# DRCSIM: Hand torque sensor - no X output

Tags: gazebo-sensor, drcsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The X component from the torque sensor of the hand is buggy. Z and Y components of the torque sensor in the wrist are giving an output while X is not. Discovered that only when the joint limits from the r_arm_mwx joint are reach the X starts giving an output.

[Hand torque sensor 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwFaM3c1TJM) shows how the Z component is performing well, while the X is giving an output only when it reaches the joint limit (2:40).

[Hand torque sensor 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMcgStZbhTs) shows how the X component gives output only in the joint limits (upper 0:31 and lower 3:20).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2651/drcsim:-hand-torque-sensor---no-x-output/) by [Alberto Romay](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/273/alberto-romay/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

moving to [issue #247 on issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/issue/247/drcsim-hand-torque-sensor-no-x-output).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1